# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - I cant see how this should occur. if statement

Tags: javascript

So ive been trying to make some code that disables a button depending on the time.. But then i thought of the time change that occurs 2 times every year. The start of november it goes back 1 hour and then in the start of may it does foward one hour. I made it but ran in to the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier". It occurs on the "if n =" statement
Thank you! i hope you understand!

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" id="checktime" value="Check"/>

<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
<!-- 
function GetMonth() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getMonth();
    console.log(n);
}
 var enableDisable = function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getMonth();
    console.log(n);

if n = 0|1|2|3|10|11 {
    one_zero = +0
{
else {
    one_zero = +1
{

var one_zero = +1;


var UTC_hours = new Date().getUTCHours() + one_zero;
console.log("Current time : " + UTC_hours)
if (UTC_hours > 19 && UTC_hours < 22){
    document.getElementById('checktime').disabled = false;
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('checktime').disabled = true;

}
};
setInterval(enableDisable, 1000*60);
enableDisable();



// -->
</script>
```

Comment: You need parentheses around the statement after `if` -- `if (n = 0|1|2|3|10|11)`

Comment: Not sure why this was closed due a typo. Writing a bad `if` statement is not a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your closing brackets are actually opening brackets and [if statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) need parentheses around the condition:

```
if (n = 0|1|2|3|10|11) {
    one_zero = +0;
} else {
    one_zero = +1;
}
```

Note that the `=` operator is the assignment operator. To check if `n` is equal to `m`, use `n === m`.

`|` is the bitwise OR operator. `n = 0|1|2|3|10|11` is equivalent to `n = 11`, which assigns `11` to the variable `n`.

To check is `n` is an element of the array `[0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11]`, use `[0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11].indexOf(n) !== -1`:

```
if ([0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11].indexOf(n) !== -1) {
    one_zero = +0;
} else {
    one_zero = +1;
}
```

Also note that `+0 === 0` and `+1 === 1`.

Comment: Nice. A slightly more full answer than my own. Good explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression should:

1) Have parenthesis

2) Use a better method for checking the numbers. At the moment you're *assigning* numbers to `n`, (use `==` or `===` to check for equality) and `|` is the bitwise `or` and won't achieve what you want.

Here I've used an array. It checks the index of `n` in the array. If `n` is not present the value returned is `-1`.

```
if ([0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11].indexOf(n) > -1) {
```